# i am facing following error while running superset db upgrade cmd

Tags: apache-superset

set_env) [root@localhost superset]# superset db upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/superset/superset_env/bin/superset", line 11, in 
load_entry_point('apache-superset==0.38.1', 'console_scripts', 'superset')()
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 476, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2700, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2318, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2324, in resolve
module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/superset/**init**.py", line 21, in 
from superset.app import create_app
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/superset/app.py", line 24, in 
from flask_appbuilder import expose, IndexView
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/**init**.py", line 5, in 
from .api import ModelRestApi  # noqa: F401
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/**init**.py", line 21, in 
from .convert import Model2SchemaConverter
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/convert.py", line 4, in 
from flask_appbuilder.models.sqla.interface import SQLAInterface
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/models/sqla/interface.py", line 40, in 
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid import UUIDType
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/**init**.py", line 1, in 
from .aggregates import aggregated  # noqa
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/aggregates.py", line 372, in 
from .functions.orm import get_column_key
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/**init**.py", line 1, in 
from .database import (  # noqa
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/database.py", line 11, in 
from .orm import quote
File "/app/superset/superset_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/orm.py", line 14, in 
from sqlalchemy.orm.query import _ColumnEntity
ImportError: cannot import name '_ColumnEntity'

i have tried to update superset and installed pillow and other dependency